# Office document saved to OneDrive cannot be found manually -- it's in a bizarre location

Tags: microsoft-word, onedrive

This has happened to me a few times on occasion. I have a Word document with auto-save turned on. It's in *OneDrive - Personal/Documents* according to the drop-down I click in the title bar. But I cannot find it in Windows explorer, and when I try to select it in the browser to upload on a website, it does not appear in the file input ("chooser") window when I navigate to *OneDrive - Personal/Documents*.

When I choose to *Save as* in Word, and click on *More options* to see what directory it starts out in, I see it's in the below non-local directory. I think the starting directory when you choose *Save as* is where the file currently resides, right? So why is the file in this bizarre directory instead of *OneDrive - Personal/Documents*? Why can't I access my file in Windows or the web browser as if it's a local file in the Documents directory?

[image]

The complete path of this directory is `https://d.docs.live.net/*gibberish*/Documents/`

Also, if I save as and choose *OneDrive - Personal/Documents*, it asks me if I want to replace the file there that already has that name.

Comment: It would appear you only have the cloud document and not a local sync copy.

Comment: It’s not “gibberish” it’s a file hash

Comment: @John I don’t know how to fix that. I thought files should automatically sync when you open them locally. I initially created the file by using save-as on a local file.

Comment: Local files on my machine are stored as   C:\Users\juser\OneDrive\Desktop\Documents\Office\Excel\My excel files

Comment: Word has its own OneDrive client. Are you sure the OneDrive sync client is set up and running?

Comment: FWIW, my Word documents are in the same One Drive folder as my Excel documents

Comment: @Tenfour04 - You have to save them to OneDrive originally for AutoSave to automatically save to OneDrive.  The file in question is equivalent of a unsaved local file.